# undefined local variable or method 'location_config_filename' - when upgrading passenger from 4 to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, upgrade

Why did I get the following error when trying to upgrade from [passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger) `4` to `5`?

```
`block in write_nginx_config_file': undefined local variable or method `location_config_filename' for #<PhusionPassenger::Standalone::StartCommand:0x007fd2dbb64030> (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the configuration file, as it changed significantly:

```
-bash> diff $(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb config/nginx.conf.erb.original 
24c24
< error_log '<%= @options[:log_file] %>' <% if @options[:log_level] >= LVL_DEBUG %>info<% end %>;
---
> error_log '<%= @options[:log_file] %>' <% if debugging? %>info<% end %>;
45c45
<     passenger_root '<%= PhusionPassenger.install_spec %>';
---
>     passenger_root '<%= location_config_filename %>';
47c47
<     passenger_ctl cleanup_pidfiles <%= serialize_strset("#{@working_dir}/temp_dir_toucher.pid") %>;
---
>     passenger_ctl cleanup_pidfiles <%= serialize_strset("#{@temp_dir}/temp_dir_toucher.pid") %>;
49,51c49,50
<     <%= nginx_option :passenger_log_level, :log_level %>
<     <%= nginx_option :passenger_max_pool_size, :max_pool_size %>
<     <%= nginx_option :passenger_min_instances, :min_instances %>
---
>     passenger_max_pool_size <%= @options[:max_pool_size] %>;
>     passenger_min_instances <%= @options[:min_instances] %>;
61,62c60,61
<     <% if @options[:instance_registry_dir] %>passenger_instance_registry_dir '<%= @options[:instance_registry_dir] %>';<% end %>
<     <% if @options[:data_buffer_dir] %>passenger_data_buffer_dir '<%= @options[:data_buffer_dir] %>';<% end %>
---
>     <% if debugging? %>passenger_log_level 2;<% end %>
>     <% if @options[:temp_dir] %>passenger_temp_dir '<%= @options[:temp_dir] %>';<% end %>
76,80c75
< 
<     <% @options[:ctls].each do |ctl| %>
<         passenger_ctl '<%= ctl.split("=", 2)[0] %>' '<%= ctl.split("=", 2)[1] %>';
<     <% end %>
< 
---
>     
96,107c91,96
< 
<     <% if @app_finder.multi_mode? %>
<         # Default server entry for mass deployment mode.
<         server {
<             <% if @options[:ssl] %>
<                 <% if @options[:ssl_port] %>
<                     listen <%= nginx_listen_address %>;
<                     listen <%= nginx_listen_address_with_ssl_port %> ssl;
<                 <% else %>
<                     listen <%= nginx_listen_address %> ssl;
<                 <% end %>
<             <% else %>
---
>     
>     <% if @apps.size > 1 %>
>     # Default server entry.
>     server {
>         <% if @options[:ssl] %>
>             <% if @options[:ssl_port] %>
108a98,100
>                 listen <%= nginx_listen_address_with_ssl_port %> ssl;
>             <% else %>
>                 listen <%= nginx_listen_address %> ssl;
110,111c102,106
<             root '<%= PhusionPassenger.resources_dir %>/standalone_default_root';
<         }
---
>         <% else %>
>             listen <%= nginx_listen_address %>;
>         <% end %>
>         root '<%= PhusionPassenger.resources_dir %>/standalone_default_root';
>     }
113a109,115
>     <% if @options[:ping_port] %>
>     server {
>         listen <%= nginx_listen_address(@options, true) %>;
>         root '<%= PhusionPassenger.resources_dir %>/standalone_default_root';
>     }
>     <% end %>
>     
138,139c140,141
<         <% if app[:concurrency_model] && app[:concurrency_model] != DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY_MODEL %>passenger_concurrency_model <%= app[:concurrency_model] %>;<% end %>
<         <% if app[:thread_count] && app[:thread_count] != DEFAULT_APP_THREAD_COUNT %>passenger_thread_count <%= app[:thread_count] %>;<% end %>
---
>         <% if app[:concurrency_model] != DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY_MODEL %>passenger_concurrency_model <%= app[:concurrency_model] %>;<% end %>
>         <% if app[:thread_count] != DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT %>passenger_thread_count <%= app[:thread_count] %>;<% end %>
142,144c144,145
<         <% if app[:sticky_sessions] %>passenger_sticky_sessions on;<% end %>
<         <% if app[:sticky_sessions_cookie_name] %>passenger_sticky_sessions_cookie_name '<%= app[:sticky_sessions_cookie_name] %>';<% end %>
<         <% if app[:vary_turbocache_by_cookie] %>passenger_vary_turbocache_by_cookie '<%= app[:vary_turbocache_by_cookie] %>';<% end %>
---
>         <% if @options[:sticky_sessions] %>passenger_sticky_sessions on;<% end %>
>         <% if @options[:sticky_sessions_cookie_name] %>passenger_sticky_sessions_cookie_name '<%= sticky_sessions_cookie_name %>';<% end %>
154,157d154
<         <% app[:envvars].each_pair do |name, value| %>
<             passenger_env_var '<%= name %>' '<%= value %>';
<         <% end %>
<
```

...including the line cited in the question:

```
<     passenger_root '<%= PhusionPassenger.install_spec %>';
---
>     passenger_root '<%= location_config_filename %>';
```